# How do I create a new user and migrate email from another account in OS X 10.6 Server?

Tags: email, mac-osx, migration, mac-osx-server

I'm having lot's of problems with one specific account that was configured before I got to administer this server. I'm thinking about removing and recreating the account, but I'm not sure how to do a backup of it's emails. That's really the only data that I need to save.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple methods - for one thing the user's email is stored in Dovecot under a folder with their UUID. If you remove the user and recreate the user with the same user ID and GUID (have to do this bit using the Inspector feature) you can avoid having to migrate the data to the new GUID/user ID. This will often times fix issues with a user that are caused by the Directory.

The easiest method to back up his/her email is to copy their folder (default location is: `/var/spool/imap/dovecot/mail/GUID`) using `ditto`. You can determine the user's GUID by either looking in Workgroup Manager or using `dscl` (eg. Local User:`dscl . read /Users/shortusername | grep GeneratedUID` or for a OD user `dscl /LDAPv3/IP_OF_OD_SERVER read /Users/shortusername | grep GeneratuedUID`). You can find more about Apple's recommended method for backing up on Page 81 of their documentation; [Mail Service Administration](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/MailServicesAdmin_v10.6.pdf)